# Route 53 redirects to URL even after deleting the Hosted Zone and Record Sets?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I had the static IP of my EC2 instance pointing to a domain (xyz.com), 5 days ago, we wanted to revert back to the standard ec2-....amazonaws.com url and not use the domain (xyz.com). I deleted the Hosted Zone and Record Sets 5 days ago.

Today when I go to the ec2-...amazonaws.com url, it redirects me to the domain (xyz.com)

I even disassociated the static IP and assigned a new IP to the EC2 instance, no change, still redirects to xyz.com

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong/missing?

Comment: Was the TTL of the old record more than 5 days?

Comment: Thats what I thought initially, but No.

Comment: the TTL for the A record was 300 and for NS - 172800

Comment: Ok, my only other idea is to clear dns cache and directly query their ns to see what it says.

Comment: The redirect is probably coming from your application. DNS does not redirect by itself.

Comment: @datasage - Do you mean to say, my index file could be redirecting to my domain? Actually, thats the reason I am confused, since DNS does not redirect. xyz.com should just display the pages hosted at ec2-...amazonaws.com. I have no clue why ec2-...amazonaws.com is being redirected to xyz.com.

Comment: @pat I suppose if you really did remove all the records, it should redirect to a page that doesn't work. If you are on a linux/mac system, you should be able to do `dig xyz.com` to see how the request is resolving. The redirect is coming from the application or web server configuration though.

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for the replies. We actually have an offshore team working on this and they did have a redirect in the header file.

I too was confused on the redirection. Thanks a lot @datasage :)